# Why is the word "item" showing up in my nested gridview query?

Tags: asp.net, linq, data-binding, datagrid

I have a query that lists team members nested in a gridview that lists projects...

```
public void GridView3_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

      if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) return;

          GridView teamnestedgridview = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridViewNested");
          int projectid = int.Parse(GridView3.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());



        var qryGetTeam = from emp in db.Employees
                            join etp in db.EmpToProjects on emp.employee_id equals etp.EmployeeID
                            where etp.ProjectID == @projectid
                            select emp.nickname;


                          teamnestedgridview.DataSource = qryGetTeam;
                            teamnestedgridview.DataBind();
```

And when I run it, within the gridview, the employees show up just fine. BUT above their names, like a header, is the word "item"...

I tried doing

first_name = emp.nickname

in the select, and then "first_name" shows up in the list instead of the word "item". Any idea how I can eliminate that "header"?

[image: teamimage]

Comment: GridView.ShowHeader = false;

Comment: Dayum. Just found that myself and was gonna answer my own question. Thank you!!!